# Is it allowed to play a youtube video within a Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, youtube, youtube-api

I've been reading the documentation about google api services and it doesn't seem clear to me if I'm allowed to use flutter packages like [youtube_player_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_flutter) to display youtube videos in a flutter mobile app. I'm talking about a mobile app that you would distribute on google play or the app store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've made an app that only searches for and plays YouTube videos. It doesn't download any video/audio. My app just got rejected from Apple. This is the rejection message:

> Jul 11, 2020 at 5:20 AM From Apple
> 5. 2.3 Legal: Intellectual Property - Audio/Video Downloading Guideline 5.2.3 - Legal
>
> Your app contains content or features that may violate the rights of
> one or more third parties. Specifically, your app provides potentially
> unauthorized access to third-party audio or video streaming, catalogs,
> and discovery services.
>
> Your app and its contents should not infringe upon the rights of
> another party. In the event your app infringes another party’s rights,
> you are responsible for any liability to Apple because of a claim.
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please attach documentary evidence in the App
> Review Information section in App Store Connect evidencing that you
> have all necessary rights or permissions to the third-party audio or
> video streaming, catalogs, and discovery services in your app.
>
> In accordance with section 3.2(f) of the Apple Developer Program
> License Agreement, you acknowledge that submitting falsified or
> fraudulent documentation can result in the termination of your Apple
> Developer Program account and the removal of your apps from the App
> Store. Once Legal has reviewed your documentation and confirms its
> validity, we will proceed with the review of your app.
>
> Resources
>
> - Review [Guideline 5.2 Intellectual Property](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#intellectual-property) for more information about appropriate uses of third-party content and services on the App
>   Store
> - Review [App Store Connect Help](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devbef8ace74) for more information on including notes in the App Review Information section of App Store Connect
>
> Please see attached screenshot for details.

Comment: Any update on this? I received the same rejection yesterday. Did you manage to approve your app?

Comment: No, the app is rejected again. After explaining that I do not store any video/audio, Apple rejected it because of legal right issues linked to 'third-party content'. They say I need to provide third-party approval, whatever that means... On the other side, I managed to publish the app for Android (Looptone).  "Guideline 5.2.3 - Legal"; "...content or features that may violate the rights of one or more third parties." "...please attach... evidencing that you have all necessary rights or permissions to the third-party audio or video streaming, catalogs, and discovery services in your app."

Comment: Hey any update on this ? Also did you display the " Youtube " logo whilst searching and playing YouTube videos as per the [Guidelines] https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/branding-guidelines

Comment: It seems the problem is that videos (in my case) are not limited to public-domain videos. Hence the 'Legal...'  issue. I have no other explanation. All of the apps that I sow on AppStore that play YouTube video play only public-domain stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You can use youtube videos for only view purpose, can't download youtube videos in flutter app, otherwise google or apple reject your app.

Answer (score 0):

it's not accepted by app store your application will get rejected

Comment: Can you provide a link and a quote which explains that assertion?