# does it legal to display YouTube videos in my flutter app

Tags: flutter, youtube

i have found this plugin `youtube_player_flutter` but i am wondering if it legal or not
before i get dive into it i need to know if it legal and appstore , google play will not reject my app or not ..

```
YoutubePlayerController _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
    initialVideoId: 'iLnmTe5Q2Qw',
    flags: YoutubePlayerFlags(
        autoPlay: true,
        mute: true,
    ),
);

YoutubePlayer(
    controller: _controller,
    showVideoProgressIndicator: true,
    videoProgressIndicatorColor: Colors.amber,
    progressColors: ProgressColors(
        playedColor: Colors.amber,
        handleColor: Colors.amberAccent,
    ),
    onReady () {
        _controller.addListener(listener);
    },
),
```

any answer guys would be grateful

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62846344/10910438 look into this thread

Comment: yes i have seen this , but i am wondering if it illegal so why this plugin is Existing

Comment: the plugin will exist, you can clone any famous app and use it for your purpose and share with your friends but you cant sell it or cant upload it to the play store or app store.

Comment: the reason i need to use this plugin is to let user choice music from YouTube and  display it in his profile .. do you think this case  is legally?

Answer (score 3):

A few link you can play using the package. I've used it and published in App & Play Store. But if you allow search and play and more functionalities like Youtube, You have high chance of your app getting rejected by Google/Apple (as mentioned in the comment you should see that thread).

Comment: the reason i need to use this plugin is to let user choice music from YouTube and display it in his profile only .. do you think this case is legally?

Comment: It seems you would like to play as well. Rather than using the whole player, I would suggest you to use url_launcher package and pass youtube url. It will simply launch the Youtube app. You don't have to worry about the rejection on App/Play store this way.

Comment: agreed with the url_launcher thing